# Scala Spark: how to compare two list of tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to find if each Tuple in my firstArray exists in my secondArray of tuple.
If it is not the case, i would like to return all tuple that doesn't match and which element of tuple exactly doesn't match.

It could be something like :
for each element (x,y) in `firstArray`:
for each element (k,z) in `secondArray`:
if (x != k) print(something)
return (x,y)
if (y != z) print(something)
return (x,y)
Example:

```
val firstArray: Array[(String,String)] = Array(("elem1","elem2"), ("elem3","elem4"))
val secondArray: Array[(String,String)] = Array(("elem1","elem2"), ("elem5","elem4"), ("elem3","elem7"))
```

**Desired output**
Output:

```
("elem3","elem4") is eliminated because elem4 doesn't match elem7
    val result: Array[(String,String)] = Array(("elem3","elem4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like

```
val res = firstArray.filterNot(secondArray.contains(_))
```

It will return the elements of first array that are not present in the second.

**Edit**

The following code will loop over the two arrays, and compare the tuples

```
for {
  (i,j) <- firstArray
  (k,l) <- secondArray
}
{
  println((i,j) match {
    case (a,b) if (a == k && b ==l) => "Tuple found"
    case (a,_) if (a == k)=> "First elem only found."
    case (_,b) if (b ==l)=> "Second elem only found."
    case _ => "No match"
  })
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this method, but actually I would like to compare each element of the tuple instead of comparing each tuple to another. This is to find out exactly which element is not present.

Comment: So maybe you can do something a little bit more complicated by looping over the two arrays, and matching the values of each to find out if they are similar or if only the first or second is similar. I'm editing the answer with a sample